# I have the following code for taking pictures, I need to know how to take video and also put a permission class for taking pictures

Tags: java, android

This first part are simple imports, not really relevant to my question.
details details android studio 
much details, such wow

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
```

Declaration of class

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Variables being declared

```
        private final static int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
        private final static int SAVE_PICTURE = 1;
        private final static int TAKE_VIDEO = 2;
        private final static int STORAGE_PERMISSION = 3;

        private ImageView iv;
        private VideoView vv;
        private MediaController mc;
        private String lastURI;
```

Basic create method, nothing special here

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            mc = new MediaController(this);

            mc.setMediaPlayer(vv);
            vv.setMediaController(mc);
        }
```

Method that takes picture

```
        public void takePicture(View v){

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
        }
```

Method that saves picture

```
        public void savePicture(View v){

            Log.i("SAVE PICTURE", "save");
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                // request permission!
                Log.i("SAVE PICTURE", "asking permission");
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                savePicturePermitted();
            }
        }
```

Main method

```
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

            Log.wtf("RETURN", requestCode + "");
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
```

Test cases

```
                switch(requestCode){

                    case TAKE_PICTURE:
                        Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
                        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)extra.get("data");
                        iv.setImageBitmap(image);
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you have to do is the following:

For the permission part use this:

```
private void savePicturePermitted(){

   // the actual code
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){

       File photo = null;
       try{

           String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date());
           String name = "GUYZ_" + time;

           File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
           photo = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg", directory);

           // keep track of the URI
           lastURI = photo.getAbsolutePath();
       }catch(IOException ioe){
           ioe.printStackTrace();
       }

       if(photo != null){
           //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
           intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photo));
           startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_PICTURE);
       }
   }
```

}

Also add a result or feedback so the user knows what's up, this could be done like so:

```
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
   super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

   if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
       savePicturePermitted();
   } else {

       Toast.makeText(this, "Permission required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

}

For taking video, the method looks like this:

public void takeVideo(View v){

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
   if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){

       startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_VIDEO);
   }
```

}

Finally, I suggest you add all of these to your test cases so you can test they work. This is how that should look like:

```
case TAKE_VIDEO:
   Uri video = data.getData();
   vv.setVideoURI(video);
   vv.start();
   break;
```

Noticed you missed a save picture use case:

```
case SAVE_PICTURE:
   Log.wtf("SAVING PICTURE", lastURI);
   Bitmap image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lastURI);
   iv.setImageBitmap(image2);
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I noticed that you were missing some imports, these should appear automatically, but in case they don't, here's what those should be:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
```